QEMU with windows 10 guest showing a blinking cursor on a black screen
So i tried to run QEMU with a windows 10 guest (installation iso). It shows the windows logo for a single frame and then shows a VGA blinking cursor. The version of windows is 22H2. I am using QCOW2. My host is Arch 6.11.4. virt-manager will not work.
Here's the command:
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda windows10.qcow2 -cdrom Desktop/Win10_22H2_English_x64v1.iso -boot d -cpu host -m 4G -vga std -net nic,model=e1000 -net user -rtc base=localtime --enable-kvm


I recommend that you use the virt-manager instead of interacting with QEMU directly. Also get the virtio for Windows drivers for better VM performance.

virt-manager is broken for some reason

As of today the virt-manager package was last updated on April 27, 2024 and there is no bug report about it. It isn't "broken". https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=virt-manager

Your OP command has nothing to do with virt-manager.

I know, OP is using QEMU directly which is not beginner friendly, so I suggested virt-manager which is easier and provides SPICE integration. I wonder what exactly is broken in OP's virt-manager. @ajgringo619

3d acceleration is broken for virt-manager and i don't know why

If you're using an Nvidia GPU, then 3d acceleration doesn't work (not caused by virt-manager). I've debated many times about a switch to AMD, but I decided awhile back to use GPU pass-through if I really need good video performance.
